# Detox build doesn't work (original one is)

Tags: android, react-native, detox, e2e

So I'm using a react native application.
When I'm building my app with the "classic" way, it's building well. When I'm trying to build with Detox, it's a complete mess, either it's in debug or release mode, and I can't make it works.
Here is my detoxrc.js file

```
    /** @type {Detox.DetoxConfig} */
module.exports = {
  testRunner: {
    args: {
      $0: 'jest',
      config: 'e2e/jest.config.js',
      jest: {
        setupTimeout: 120000,
      },
    },
  },
  apps: {
    'ios.debug': {
      type: 'ios.app',
      binaryPath: 'ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app',
      build:
        'xcodebuild -workspace ios/App.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build',
    },
    'ios.release': {
      type: 'ios.app',
      binaryPath: 'ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app',
      build:
        'xcodebuild -workspace ios/App.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build EXCLUDED_ARCHS=arm64',
    },
    'android.debug': {
      type: 'android.apk',
      binaryPath: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
      testBinaryPath: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk',

      build: 'cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug',
      reversePorts: [8081],
    },
    'android.release': {
      type: 'android.apk',
      binaryPath: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk',
      build: 'cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release',
    },
  },
  devices: {
    simulator: {
      type: 'ios.simulator',
      device: {
        type: 'iPhone 14 Plus',
      },
    },
    attached: {
      type: 'android.attached',
      device: {
        adbName: '.*',
      },
    },
    emulator: {
      type: 'android.emulator',
      device: {
        avdName: 'Pixel_6_API_33',
      },
    },
  },
  configurations: {
    'ios.sim.debug': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.debug',
    },
    'ios.sim.release': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.release',
    },
    'android.att.debug': {
      device: 'attached',
      app: 'android.debug',
    },
    'android.att.release': {
      device: 'attached',
      app: 'android.release',
    },
    'android.emu.debug': {
      device: 'emulator',
      app: 'android.debug',
    },
    'android.emu.release': {
      device: 'emulator',
      app: 'android.release',
    },
  },
}
```

Basically,
on android I'm having this issue :

```
One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:
     
     Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 31 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':react-native-community_progress-view' is 'android-30'
```

I know it's probably not detox related, but why I'm then having this issue on a Detox build and not a classic build ?
However, I don't want to use the config using `androidTest - app-debug-androidTest.apk` config. Just the classic one located there `outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

Help is really welcome.

Thanks